# Perform calculation on a list

Tags: python, list, math

I got a list like this: `my_list = [5, 9, 3, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6]`
And it can have an undefined number of integers in it. I need to perform a calculation between the numbers that ignores the second number and calculate something like this: `(5 - 3) + (4 - 8) + 7` and then repeat the process.

I have tried a for loop like this one:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    print(my_list[i])
```

But it seems wrong and I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Do you want the calculation or you want to print the list like `(5 - 3) + (4 - 8) + 7`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Could you have a better example, with some markups so I can fallow it better?

Comment: I just want the calculation result like `5 - 3 + 4 - 8 + 7 = 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the sum:

```
  my_list[0] - my_list[2]
+ my_list[3] - my_list[5]
+ my_list[6] - ...
```

The elements in the left column, with a `+` sign, are the elements of the slice `my_list[::3]`. The elements in the right column, with a `-` sign, are the elements of the slice `my_list[2::3]`.

**Solution:**

Thus the function you are looking for is:

```py
def f(my_list):
  return sum(my_list[::3]) - sum(my_list[2::3])

# f([5, 9, 3, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6]) == 5
```

**Iterating to print intermediary results:**

If you want to print the intermediary results, you can iterate through `my_list[::3]` and `my_list[2::3]` simultaneously using `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

for a,b in zip_longest(my_list[::3], my_list[2::3], fillvalue=0):
  print('{} - {} = {}'.format(a, b, a-b))

# OUTPUT:
# 5 - 3 = 2
# 4 - 8 = -4
# 7 - 0 = 7
```

**See also:**

- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)
- [builtin function `zip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`itertools.zip_longest` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Answer (score 1):

A nice Pythonic way to achieve it would be with `itertools`:

```
from itertools import compress, cycle

my_list = [5, 9, 3, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6]
# Choose first and third items of each 3
narrowed = compress(my_list, cycle([1,0,1])) 
# Alternate between positive and negative numbers
signs = map(lambda x,y: x*y, narrowed, cycle([1,-1]))
# Sum everything
sum(signs)
```

Or in one line:

```
sum(map(lambda x,sign: sign*x, compress(my_list, cycle([1,0,1])), cycle([1,-1])))
```

- `cycle` - infinitely repeat an iterator
- `compress` - allow you to choose a subset by a bit sign
- `map` - applies a function on an iterator
- `sum` - sums

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Efficient Solution.

```py
score = 0
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 3):
    j = i+2
    if j < len(my_list):
        score +=  my_list[i] - my_list[j]
    else:
        score += my_list[i]
print(score)
```

Comment: did you check b4 posting it here?

Comment: yes, please set indentation according to your editor.

Comment: your code doesn't satisfy the op's conditions completely. It only prints 2 and -4 what about the sum as the op asked?